# recvfrom - receiving arbitrary-sized structs?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am making a chat client that receives structs of info from the server over a UDP socket in varying amounts. Each one of these structs starts with a header that tells the client what type of struct it is. Is it possible to use `recvfrom` to retrieve the entire struct, no matter what the size is, and then cast it to whatever struct I need based on the header, or do I first have to read the header, determine the struct, and then read in the struct piece by piece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only receive UDP packets as complete datagrams.  You have to do a `recvfrom` with a buffer large enough for any message and then cast it appropriately.

Comment: OK this is perfect then, so if I know that a packet has a max size of say 128 bytes, the recvfrom won't continue to block if I request that much but only get a struct of 16 bytes?

Comment: Correct.  It will receive at most 128 bytes from a single datagram.  If someone only sends 16 bytes, then `recvfrom` will only return 16 bytes.